# "Force relogin after Login-As-User" - But why?

Tags: security

In our health check, it is noted that we do not have "Force relogin after Login-As-User" enabled. Per the documentation, I can see what this checkbox does - but there is not much documentation on why this is considered a medium risk to security if we do NOT have it enabled. Anyone know good reasons why this is needed and/or a medium security risk?